# Writing to an element in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an integer array of monthSales, obviously the length of 12, what does it mean to "write a statement that writes to standard output the element corresponding to October"?

Is writing to an element in an array different from assigning said element to a previously defined variable?

Comment: writing to standard output means displaying the value on the console screen (usually)

Answer (score 3):

Since the array index starts from 0, October Month will corresponds to `index` 9

```
System.out.println("Your sales for month of October is" + monthSales[9]);
```